# Update value of a row of listview in a fragment from activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have an activity which has tabs(fragments) in it. Each fragment has a listview. The activity also consists of a button, which on clicked pops out a dialog box having an increment and decrement button in it.

How can I change value of item of listview when users presses increment/decrement button in the dialog box?

Activity A, Layout{viewpager,button}
Frgament B, Layout{listview}

Comment: just have the adapter reference inside activity and when you click on the button inside activity , just change the value of adapter accordingly and  call notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: getActivity().runUIThread{
 new Runnable(){
   adapter.notifyDataSetchanged();
}
}